# How to add multiple permissions and properties to a characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is only one constructor for type [BluetoothGattCharacteristic](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html)

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic(UUID uuid, int properties, int permissions)
```

Does the constructor take exactly one property and one permission?

For example, I want a characteristic to be both readable and writable. Doesn't this means I need two sets of permission-property pairs?

```
PERMISSION_READ
PROPERTY_READ
```

and

```
PERMISSION_WRITE
PROPERTY_WRITE
```

But according to the constructor, I can only set one permission and property when I need two of each right? So how do I add multiple permissions and properties to a characteristic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a characteristic both read and write?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341515/how-to-make-a-characteristic-both-read-and-write)