# How to make a characteristic both read and write?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I understand that a characteristic can have only one property and one permission, and that the property must have the same value as the permission e.g. a characteristic must have the property of being writable if it has permission to be written to... so how can I make a characteristic readable AND writable?

e.g.

How to turn this

```
int permission = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE;
int property = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE;
```

Into read **and** write

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple permissions and properties to a characteristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341064/how-to-add-multiple-permissions-and-properties-to-a-characteristic)

Answer (score 3):

Use a mask

```
int permission = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ;
int property = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE|BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ;
```